# Angular2+ use integrity parameter for a local script file

Tags: spring, angular, subresource-integrity

I have 2 scripts in the asset folder of angularjs. I generated the integrity hashes for them using https://hash.online-convert.com/sha384-generator. In my localhost everything is working fine. But in server only IE works, but firefox and chrome tell that hash does not match content. Here is example of how the files are included:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-aL/wpCLJCv6t5sBNGKKvqcvD4HI7ELd0TsuutAmgCJcNpe0y7D5ECI62DIOy5Xyl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

API is implemented with Java Spring and this security header is also added:

```
.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))
```

Why wont firefox and chrome validate correctly with the integrity hash in the webserver? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it this way. We ended up using angular-cli where the scripts were but under the "script": tag. And the building it with angular cli 1.5+ with the addition of tag --subresouce-integrity